# WebView Android doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a problem with Android App. I made a WebView and it opens the website. But buttons in the websites don't work. When i press them Activity just closes.

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    WebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebView.loadUrl(website);
```

Comment: `just closes` check the logcat for exceptions. Also show what the buttons should do

Comment: There is nothing shown in LogChat but i understood that Activity doesn't close - WebView does when i press "menu" button

Comment: first you say that `Activity just closes`, then you say that `understood that Activity doesn't close`. Plerase choose

Comment: Web View closes

Comment: WebView can't close, as it is the view. Activity can close

Comment: I don't now what happens but when i press a website button i can see only blank activity where webView supposed to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your issue is that links are not working in your `WebView`? If that's the case, this is simply because you need to add an instance of a `WebViewClient` to your `WebView`. You can simply do this:

`WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

If you want more control over what happens when a user clicks a link, you can check out the Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview) under the section "Handling Page Navigation".